# parse.com get value from database; if quote does not work

Tags: javascript, android, parse-platform

I am writing some Cloude Code on Parse.com. As basis I use the cloud database service from Parse. In database table "Transaction" I manage all my reservations. I want a method, that can be called from the android client to check, if the user already checked in (check in gets set in another method). Therefor I'm just trying to make an If-Quote. The comparison is not working, how can I get only one value from my database to run the IF?

Input: transactinID --> search for ID, get checkin value (boolean) --> check if checkin is treu/false

My code:

```
Parse.Cloud.define("checkIfCheckedIn", function(request, response) {
//get user infoarmation
var transactionID = request.params.transactionID;

var check = new Parse.Query("Transaction");
check.get(transactionID, {
    success: function(check){
        if(check.checkin == true) {
            response.success("true");
        }else{
            response.success("false");
        };
    },
    error: function(error)  {
        alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
    }
});
```

});

Comment: Is transactionID the object id of Transaction?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should use "get" method on result object.

From docs:

> To get the values out of the Parse.Object, use the get method.
>   https://parse.com/docs/js/guide#objects-retrieving-objects

Answer (score 0):

You did not answer my comment yet, but here is a suggestion. Here you should replace the equalTo with the column that holds the transactionID in your Transaction class.

```
var Transaction  = Parse.Object.extend("Transaction");
var query = new Parse.Query(Transaction);
query.equalTo('transactionID', transactionID);    
query.first( {
    success: function(check){
        if(check.get('checkin')) {
            response.success("true");
        }else{
            response.success("false");
        };
    },
    error: function(error)  {
        alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
    }
});
```

If it is the case that transactionID indeed is supposed to be equal to the object ID, then I cannot see how the client can ever provide an ID to ask against (if it does not already exist).

Actually, perhaps what you really want is:

```
var Transaction  = Parse.Object.extend("Transaction");
var query = new Parse.Query(Transaction);
query.equalTo('transactionID', transactionID);    
query.first( {
    success: function(check){
        if(check.get('checkin')) {
            response.success("true");
        }else{
            response.success("false");
        };
    },
    error: function(error)  {
        // transaction not found
        response.success("false");            

        // you might want to inspect the error
        // to ensure that it is indeed object not foun
        // and not a timeout or other error

        // alert does not work in cloud coud
        //alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);

        // console does, however
        console.error(error.message);
    }
});
```

Oh just noticed now, also:

```
check.checkin == true
```

Should be

```
check.get('checkin') == true
```

Or simply

```
check.get('checkin')
```

Parse objects in javascript are accessed by setter/getters and not via properties. Corrected the code above accordingly.

Comment: Thank you! I will try this later. so, if I want to get a value out of an object I always have to use query.get("")? I have the same issue on another method, where I want to read out a value from the query, save as variable and use it in another query

Comment: No problem. Well, not `query.get()`, but `parseObject.get()`, however got a feeling that was what you meant. I do not know your current level of understanding with regards to parse and javascript, but I would recommend that you look into the documentation about `promise`. Promises in javascript makes these types of chaining of events much cleaner and simple. Otherwise just add the code in your question and I will have a look at it.